# How can you create S-GATE with U3?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

Hello I am trying to create an Q0->HSSH Q1->HSH using U3 Gate only.

I am trying U3(pi/2, 0, pi) for H Gate and U3(4*pi/2, 2*pi,0) for S gate.

The output state vector using normal H and S gate don't seem to match the output from U3. Am I not understanding something correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the Hadamard gate correct, but not the S-gate.

The U3-gate is quite versatile, as it can be used to construct many other standard [gates](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/single-qubit-gates.html). For example:
\begin{align*}
    U_3 (\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}, \phi= 0, \lambda=\pi) &= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta/2) & -e^{-i\lambda}\sin(\theta/2) \\
    e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2) & e^{i(\lambda + \phi)}\cos(\theta/2)
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= 
    \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi/4) & -(-1)\sin(\pi/4) \\
    1 \sin(\pi/4) & -1 \cos(\pi/4)
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
With:
\begin{align*}
  \cos{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},
\end{align*}
we are able to construct a Hadamard gate:
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow
    U_3 (\frac{\pi}{2}, 0, \pi) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = H 
\end{align*}

Another example is how to construct the flexible phase gate $U_1$ (with which we can generate the P-gate, S-gate, and T-gate):
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow
    U_3 (0, 0, \lambda) &= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta/2) & -e^{-i\lambda}\sin(\theta/2) \\
    e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2) & e^{i(\lambda + \phi)}\cos(\theta/2)
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda} \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= U_1.
\end{align*}
Specifically, to generate a Z-gate:
$$
  U_3(0, 0, \pi) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = Z
$$
And, similarly, the S-gate:
$$
  U_3(0, 0, \pi/2) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix} = S
$$

Comment: Awesome that helps yeah I found my mistake, I was putting pi in lambda thinking the multiplication should lead to i, but turns out I cannot do basic trigonometry lol

Comment: You may want to give my answer the check mark as being The Answer ;-)